# Is deinit Guaranteed to be Called When the Program Finishes?

Tags: swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, destructor

I have the following code:

```
class Problem{
    init(){
        print("Problem init");
    }
    deinit{
        print("Problem deinit");
    }
    
}
var list = Problem();
```

The output:

> Problem init

The following causes the program to call `deinit`:

```
class Problem{
    init(){
        print("Problem init");
    }
    deinit{
        print("Problem deinit");
    }
    
}
do {
    var list = Problem();
}
```

**Questions:**

- Why isn't `deinit` called the first time?
- Is there a way to guarantee that `deinit` will always be called for `Problem` in code that I have not control of how it is written(i.e., user code)?

**P.S.** I know there is most likely an obvious reason that I, as a programmer that is new to Swift, have overlooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the difference in Scopes between these two example that you create by adding the `do-block`.

In the first scenario, when that code is ran, an instance of `Problem` is created (initialized) at a Global Scope (outside of a class or struct definition in Swift) and then it just sits there. The program does not end and it is never de-initialized.

In the second scenario, you create the instance of `Problem` inside a the `do-block`, so it's scope is limited to inside that block. When the `do-block` ends, the instance is dereferenced, and thus de-initialized.